# How to use Git with file too big (>100mb) for Git LFS?

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, github, git-lfs

How does one manage a file (.obj) that's too big for Git LFS?

It has a 100mb limit (https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files/)

For a project in Unity, I'm unable to push this file 113mb.

Comment: No it doesn't - GitHub has a limitation of 10 MB on files that are _not_ in Git LFS.  Supporting large files is the entire point of Git LFS.

Comment: [`Git LFS lets you store files up to 2 GB in size.`](https://help.github.com/articles/versioning-large-files/). Are you sure you configured Git-LFS correctly to track your `.obj` files in the `.gitattributes` ?

Answer (score 5):

GitHub has a 100 MB size limitation on files that are *not* in Git LFS.

If you're unable to push, then your file is not *actually* in Git LFS.  Make sure that you've [removed *every version* of the file from your history](https://help.github.com/articles/moving-a-file-in-your-repository-to-git-large-file-storage/).  It is not merely enough to take a large file that has been committed and turn on Git LFS.  The old versions remain - as large files - in history.

Comment: You remove the files in the previous commits by `git commit --amend`

Comment: That works when the files are only in the previous commit, and not in commits further in history, or in different branches.  You'll need to either use git filter-branch or BFG Repo Cleaner in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

Use a host with larger size limits (like bitbucket). The problem is with github limits, not with git lfs.

Comment: Github limit is not the issue here, the file not being in LFS is.